# execution behavior is different when the program is run without debugger and with it

Tags: linux, ddd-debugger

I am running a program in linux. The behavior of the program is different when i run it in ddd debugger and without it.  That is the program halts at different points. Why is it so? Is it debugger dependent or it happens sometimes with every debugger?

Comment: What do you mean by "halts" ? Are talking about breakpoints ? Blocking functions ? Runtime errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description is not very precise but it sounds like a memory access issue.

When you have invalid memory access in your code, the behavior is undefined and may be different with gdb connected. For memory errors, you should try to run a memory profiler like Valgrind.